# WPF to XPS with outline and structure

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument, xps, fixeddocument

I am developing a WPF reporting application. 
My report is constructed as WPF Control (FlowDocument or FixedDocument) and 
contains tables. I want to save it as XPS preserving its structure (this means that I can copy a table as a table, not plain text like explained in this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771384(v=vs.90).aspx)). I found a way to save WPF Control with XpsDocumentWriter or XpsSerializationManager, but the result has no structure or outline.
 Is it possible to save WPF Control as Xps preserving its structure?

Comment: You can definitely generate an XPS document from a `FlowDocument` as we do this in one of our applications at work. I'm still not entirely clear on what you mean by "preserving its structure" though. Could you expand on this a little more in your question?

Comment: A FlowDocument is not a WPF control is it a .NET Class.  FlowDocumentScrollViewer is a WPF Control.

Comment: @Dmitry B - OK after following the link and a little Googling I'm a bit clearer on what you're after. Unfortunately this seems to be an area of XPS that is rarely used and there seems to be very little documentation out there or people using it. In principle you should be able to determine the structure based on the content of the `FlowDocument`, but the existing methods that I know of for generating XPS from `FlowDocument` elements won't give you the level of control over the resulting ZIP structure that you will need to implement this I don't think.

Comment: @Blam Sorry, by WPF Control I implied WPF Elements that can be serialized to Xps document.

Comment: @StevenRands Yes that's what I was looking for. After some investigation I wrote an answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

XPS is a fixed document format, and WPF allows you to save a FlowDocument to a FixedDocument as a XPS file, code is needed when you want to add more features, you can follow this article to go further in that.

[Convert XAML Flow Document to XPS with Style (multiple page, page size, header, margin)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fyuan/archive/2007/03/10/convert-xaml-flow-document-to-xps-with-style-multiple-page-page-size-header-margin.aspx)

Comment: This article mentions XpsSerializationManager, but it seems that you cannot use this class to add structure to resulting Xps document.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no way to preserve WPF element semantics when serializing it with `XpsDocumentWriter` or `XpsSerializationManager`.
The only way to construct a document with structure is using low-level API from `System.Windows.Xps.Packaging` namespace, as described in this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163664.aspx). Using this API you can obtain `XmlWriter` for constructing `FixedPage` content

```
XpsDocument document = new XpsDocument(destFileName,FileAccess.ReadWrite); 
IXpsFixedDocumentSequenceWriter docSeqWriter = document.AddFixedDocumentSequence(); 
IXpsFixedDocumentWriter docWriter = docSeqWriter.AddFixedDocument(); 
IXpsFixedPageWriter pageWriter = docWriter.AddFixedPage();
XmlWriter xmlWriter = pageWriter.XmlWriter;
```

and a `Stream` for writing document structure

```cs
XpsResource storyFraments = pageWriter.AddStoryFragment();
Stream stream = storyFraments.GetStream();
```

Although there are classes in the `System.Windows.Documents.DocumentStructures` namesapace representing `StoryFragments` elements and it’s children, you cannot use them while writing to the resource stream.